# How to add do_deploy task to a Qt6 CMake Yocto recipe that deploys an application binary to the build's deployment directory?

Tags: qt, cmake, yocto, bitbake, qt6

I have a recipe that builds and installs a Qt application to targets rootfs using `qt6-cmake` from `meta-qt6`, it works fine.

```
inherit qt6-cmake

SRC_URI += "<SNIP>"

DEPENDS += "\
    <SNIP> \
"

RDEPENDS:${PN} += "<SNIP>"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

I would like to extend the recipe with a `do_deploy` task that writes the Qt application binary to the build's deployment directory.

```
inherit deploy
/* SNIP */
do_deploy() {
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}
    install -m 0755 ???  ${DEPLOYDIR}/foo
}

add_task deploy after do_package
```

The problem is, I don't know what `???` should be. Where should the Qt application binary be deployed from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
inherit deploy
/* SNIP */
do_deploy() {
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/package${bindir}/foo ${DEPLOYDIR}/foo
}

addtask deploy after do_package
```